# working with Bitbucket docker image

Tags: docker, server, bitbucket

I am trying to use bitbucket docker image as documented in the below link.

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/docker-atlassian-bitbucket-server

I progressed to

1. bring up the container.
2. hit the url and create admin user.

But it does not log me in.

```
The message is invalid userId/password.
```

The reset wont work because being a container, the mail service is not set up.

I cannot proceed past this and it is frustrating.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You tried to login with the admin user you just created? Are you sure you used that password?

Comment: Yes. It just brings back the login screen suggesting invalid userid/password.

Comment: I went for the container setup so that I can quickly test a repository hook. But this is holding up the progress.